# How do I get two Miis to be friends instantly?

Tags: tomodachi-life

How can I get 2 Miis to instantly be friends, no matter what the percentage is in the Compatibility Tester? If I add too many Miis, nobody talks to each other, and it feels like 5 days before anything happens. But if I only have a few, Miis are always asking to be friends.

Answer (score 1):

It's all random. You have to wait for a mii to say they want to be friends with another Mii. If you pick yes then he/she will talk to the other mii and they will become friends.

Hope this helps!!